# going crazy with Windows 10 Mail and image sizes

Tags: html, css, html-email

My images are big originally, to make them look good on high DPI displays. my html email template works well everywhere except Windows outlook 2013 and Windows 10 mail. The images look GIANT on those clients, and my width/height inline CSS is ignored.

Is there anything I can do? This images comes up as a 500 pixel image...

```
<img width="60px" height="30px" style="margin: 20px" src="myImage.png">
```

Comment: did you try style="width: 60px; height: 30px" ?

Comment: Yes.a Doesn't work. it's still giant.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `px` in `width="60px" height="30px"`. I'm pretty sure those inline attributes only requires a value without any text, so `width="60" height="30"`. This is because the inline attributes already expects a value in pixel, so no need to specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has nothing to do with your image or inline CSS.

Image size in Microsoft Outlook and Windows Mail gets affected by the display settings of Windows 8/8.1/10.

Try putting your display size at 100% and don't forget to sign out of Windows before trying again.

Comment: So everyone viewing OP's email template has to set the display settings scale to 100% in order to see it as expected?

Answer (score 6):

This is not valid HTML:

```
<img width="60px" height="30px" style="margin: 20px" src="myImage.png">
```

You have to mostly ignore CSS, as HTML email is stuck well into the past.  Units are disallowed in the width and height attribute - it's always pixels.  Try this:

```
<img width="60" height="30" style="margin: 20px" src="myImage.png">
```

I'm not sure that HTML email support has improved for CSS.  You'll be unlikely to get a margin to work like that in all mail clients.  You'll be better served by wrapping in a table, and making the table cell around the image look something like

```
<td cellpadding="20"><img width="60" height="30" src="myImage.png"></td>
```

Also, I'm fairly certain that the standard for High DPI display of email would be maybe 2x or 3x the display resolution.  Why are you using a 500px image?  Shrink it to 120px and it should look fine, as most devices right now aren't scaling more than 2x.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use margin in emails, it isnt supported in outlook.com/hotmail.com, use padding instead. 
Width and height should not have px at the end, Outlooks dosnt understand this for some odd reason.

```
<td style="padding:20px">
 <img width="60" height="30" src="myImage.png">
</td>
```